# SwiftUI State Variable not Rendering View Unless Used Inside View (verses in modifier)

Tags: swiftui, state, swiftui-state

Sorry for terrible wording, but in onAppear I am changing a State variable, however this does not re-render the view unless I use that State variable somewhere inside the view.

I am trying to pop a modal if the user is not logged in, but it won't pop unless I put the variable in the view like shown below

```
struct SearchView: View {
// Environment Variables
@EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

@State var sheetIsPresented: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        // Just having a line like this will cause it to work
        if self.sheetIsPresented || !self.sheetIsPresented {}
    }
    .onAppear {
        if self.session.userSession != nil {
            self.sheetIsPresented = true
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsPresented) {
        WelcomeSignInModal(sheetIsPresented: self.$sheetIsPresented)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Works fine here. Are you sure `self.session.userSession != nil` this condition is true at the moment you test it?

Comment: @Asperi Yup. Breakpoint is hit and if I put in a Text("\(sheetIsPresented)") in the body, it'll show true and pop the modal.

Comment: having the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following demo:

```
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    var userSession: String? = "session"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

    @State var sheetIsPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("SearchView")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.sheetIsPresented = self.session.userSession != nil
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsPresented) {
            Text("WelcomeSignInModal")
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 11.6, iOS 13.6

Comment: Still not working for me on Xcode 11.6 and iOS 13.6.1. Requires me to include the useless line. Must be something related to how I get the userSession

Comment: @connorvo The code above works with a mocked SessionStore, maybe post a minimal, reproducible version of your *actual* SessionStore?